# What happened to Sophie and her family in "Hanna"

Tags: plot-explanation, hanna

In the movie *Hanna*, with Saoirse Ronan, Eric Bana, and Cate Blanchett, what happened to Sophie (Jessica Barden) and her family? Can we assume that Marissa murdered them?
That's what I got when she said, "Some days I really hate my job."

Comment: All dead . . No doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**We don't know definitively**.

We can certainly speculate though. A lot appears to depend on whether you want a *happy* ending or a *sad* ending.

**Happy**

In the [*original* script for the film](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Hanna.pdf), Sophie (and therefore presumably the family) get quite a nice ending. Towards the end of the linked script is the following:

> Sophie comes out in her school uniform. It’s a bright summer’s day. As
>   she walks down the garden path, she reaches and meets the Postman.
>
> **SOPHIE** Morning handsome.
>
> He hands her a POSTCARD. Sophie opens the
>   garden gate, reading the POSTCARD, there’s nothing on the back. On the
>   front, PLANET EARTH. Sophie knows exactly who it’s from.
>
> **HANNA (V.O.)**
>   ...Earth is the only place in the universe where life is known to
>   exist.
>
> She walks down the street and the vast cityscape of LONDON
>   spreads out in front of her.

**Sad (and partially unconfirmed)**:

In the [*finished* script for the film](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Hanna.html), these happy lines are removed from the ending:

> HANNA steps out of the cabin. She's back wearing her furs
>                 again. In her hands she carries a cup of hot milk and a small
>                 wooden bowl.
>                 In VOICE-OVER we hear HANNA reading from her beloved
>                 Encyclopaedia.
>
> **HANNA (V.O.)**
>                 The Earth is the third planet from
>                 the Sun, and the fifth-largest of
>                 the eight planets in the Solar
>                 System.
>                 HANNA sits down on a tree trunk outside the cabin and pours
>                 some milk into the bowl, then drinks a little for herself.
>
> **HANNA (V.O.)** Home to millions of species,
>                 including humans, ***Earth is the only
>                 place in the universe where life is
>                 known to exist.***
>                 She raises her head and makes a small clicking sound. Her
>                 friend, the snow fox, appears from the trees. The fox now has
>                 a small family of cubs.
>                 HANNA watches as the cubs approach the milk and begin to
>                 drink.

The highlighted section is what was said to Sophie on the postcard in the original script. As this scene has been removed, it certainly doesn't suggest anything *good* for poor Sophie and Miles.

As their fates are left unknown, I'd suggest it's nothing good and it's very likely they are dead.

[TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/Hanna) does state: "A (German) poster later in the [film] says they are missing, so we can assume it was nothing good."

However, I haven't been able to confirm this (not least since I can't speak to German).

Comment: Thank you for these links. I will try to re-watch the movie and catch the poster scene. My German is middlin' fair. Let you know.